# why we need to use the Schema name for Scalar functions only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have created two functions one is table-valued function and second one is scalar-valued function. while calling the table-valued function I don't need to use the Schema name but for the Scalar-valued function I need schema. my question is why? as both are the user defined functions.

Table-valued Function

```
SELECT * FROM split ('1,2,3',',')
```

Scalar-valued Function

```
SELECT dbo.GetESTDate()
```

Comment: One is a scalar function and the other is like a table. They are different objects in sql server. It would be nice if they were consistent but they aren't. Honestly you should use the schema for everything anyway.

Comment: It is highly recommended to specify schema all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Yours is an interesting question. I'm actually not sure what the official reason is but I can point you to Microsoft's [CREATE FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) documentation which does in fact indicate that you must use at least two-part naming when calling scalar functions.

> Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least the two-part name of the function. [(Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx)

I'll dig around a bit more and see if I can't get more information. You've got me interested too.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any particular information that points to a reason. Most people just call it a SQL Server quirk. My speculation is that there is some internal working that causes it to be possible to omit the schema name when referencing table-like objects (e.g. tables, views and table-valued functions since they produce tables) but not with other objects. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is Sql Server rule.
Even if you don't need to use schema for TVF, PLEASE use it always! Imagine that someone implements built-in "split" function in SQL Server and your code will break because it will be in collision with built-in TVF. Even if you don't use schema add some prefix like ufn.

Comment: JocaPC: I can understand that we use the schema with everything whether it is a simple query on table. Even if we use the schema name then it will also improve some performance. Actually I would like to know why it is not required with SVF not with TVF.